# Add confirm dialogue check before .on() event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a confirm dialogue check before the handler executes for a .on("click") event in jquery. This is the original:

```
$(this.var_mainSelector).on("click",
    this.var_acceptOfferSelector,
    this.onAcceptOffer
);
```

I've tried:

```
$(this.var_mainSelector).on("click", this.var_acceptOfferSelector, 
    function() {
        var test = confirm("are u sure?");
        if(test) {
            this.onAcceptOffer
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

almost ;) the closure itself defines a new "this", so `this.onAcceptOffer` isn't defined anymore.

**Solutions**

1) save this in self

```
var self = this;
$(this.var_mainSelector).on("click", this.var_acceptOfferSelector, function(evt) {
    var test = confirm("are u sure?");
    if(test) {
        self.onAcceptOffer.call(this, evt);
    }
});
```

2) Don't use `function`. Instead use `()=>`

```
$(this.var_mainSelector).on("click", this.var_acceptOfferSelector, (evt)=>{
    var test = confirm("are u sure?");
    if(test) {
        this.onAcceptOffer.call(null, evt); // original "this" (the clicked element) is lost
    }
});
```

arrow functions ("()=>") are not changing the context of the function

Comment: You need to call the function `self.onAcceptOffer()`

Comment: Thank you so much JoshuaK Appreciate not only the answer, but the explanation behind it, and comparative solution.
And to you too @Barmar